# how to debug a php post script on the server and see echo output

Tags: php

newbie question. I have a web page sending $_POST data to a php script on a server.
How to debug php (see the output of echo) ?
If I just browse to the www.serveradress.com/myscript.php,I see nothing...
I am using Chrome.

Thanks

Edit: I am using ngFileUpload on the client side.
Edit: I see that the file is well received because I see it on the server with filezilla.

client side:

```
$scope.uploadBoardPic = function(file, errFiles) {
    $scope.boardPic = file;
    $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
    if (file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: 'http://myserver.com/angular-seed/appendBoardPicture.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {file: file}
        });

        file.upload.then(function (response) {
            $timeout(function () {
                file.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.status > 0)
                $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function (evt) {
            file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
    }   
}
```

server side:

```
<?php
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$destination = './' . $filename;
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , $destination );

echo "<pre>" . print_r($_FILES, true) . "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Would `die(var_dump($_POST))` before the `require_once` work for you?

Comment: Var_dump and exit in your php and console log from your angular. See it inchrome console

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I tried die..., error_log, and echo "<pre>" , but I get nothing on the php page

Comment: What is this Upload JavaScript library you're using? I would try reading some documentation on that first.

Answer (score 1):

Php keeps POST variables within the $_POST global.  You should be able to run something to the affect of

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";
```

To get back the debugging information you need.  This of course will only work if you are doing a valid POST via a form.  That meaning that the page is actually going to change.  Looking at your question though, it looks like you are working in all javascript for your post/reply.  In that case, you will want to look for the reply information from php, within your javascript.  You can do this by looking at the network tab, during the submission.

Comment: Hi I just tried and I get nothing when browsing to myserver.com/angular-seed/appendBoardPicture.php... just an empty
`Array
(
)`

Comment: If you are printing out the $_POST global, and getting nothing but an empty array, then you have not sent the info across correctly.  You can test this simply by using something like POSTMAN in Chrome, to send a direct POST request to your URL.  

To start troubleshooting, I would send a static string from your clientside script.  From there you can troubleshoot what is and isnt making it across.

Comment: If this answer helped you to debug, please accept it as the chosen one.  Thanks!

Comment: For now, It didnt help because when the PHP file is served when i browse to it, the post variables have been sent yet. How to refresh the php rendering when the post variables is received on the server ? Do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: You would need to submit the post with your javascript, and then check for the reply within the network tab of your console (chrome or firefox) for the var_dump or echo output.  Since your input is from js, in this regard, your output will be received in js as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, you should use error logs for this kind of task. If you have not set up a error log then you should set it up in the apache config file.

Once you set the error log simply type this:

```
error_log(var_export($_POST, true));
```

and you can see the exports in your error log.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: I would like to have something simpler than opening the error logs to debug and build my php script.

Comment: But thats how you debug a PHP script. Most good PHP developers SSH to the development server and monitors error log and debugs the code. Its a very good practice. "Echo" or "var_dump" is not a good practice for debuggin because if you are calling the script from ajax, you wont see the dump or echo.

Comment: Oh ok, I believe you. Thanks for your confirmation. I am going to ask how to reach my error logs. Can you tell which type of error logs should I ask for to my server admin ?